# How to set value of extern variable?

Tags: c, visual-c++, extern, parsec, unresolved-external

I am using glomosim simulator for my networking practise.
and one of the file of routing protocol under network layer has following line. The filename is "**ARAN.pc**" (i got this file from internet, i want to replace aodv protocol which is by default set in simulator with authenthicated routing protocol i.e ARAN):

`extern int maliciousNodesPercentage; //defined and set in driver.pc`

when I compile simulator (using a bat file) shows me this error:

`*call pcc -user_main -Zi  -Ox    -I..\include\ -clock longlong -o ..\bin\glomosim driver.pc temp.lib 
tmp-3572-0.c
driver.init.c
temp.lib(aran.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _maliciousNodesPercentage
..\bin\glomosim.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals*`

When I opened `driver.pc` file I did not find **maliciousNodesPercentage**.

How do I set the value of the variable?

Answer (score 1):

An external variable has to be declared `somewhere`. If you just use `extern int maliciousNodesPercentage` it ust tells the compiler that this variable is defined in some other module, so no storage is allocated for it. In the linking stage the linker will then put in the actual adress of the variable. Since you didn't define it anywhere, you get an unresolved symbol.

For example in `main` you define as a global variable:

```
  int  maliciousNodesPercentage;
```

and in all other modules (or in a header file) you do:

```
  extern int maliciousNodesPercentage;
```

Then you can access it just like any other global variable.